# restrict decimal number only for 2 places

Tags: javascript

this function is working properly but i dnt wan to round of my number..this function round of my number.

```
jquery( function() {
    $('.two-digits').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().indexOf('.')!=-1){         
            if($(this).val().split(".")[1].length > 2){ 

                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            }  
         }            
         return this; //for chaining
    });
});
```

Comment: If the function does something that you don't want, then it is *not* working properly…

Comment: Have you written this yourself? Do you understand what it does? Where is your problem with fixing the functionality?

Comment: note that unless you've done something hinky, jQuery is spelled, well like that

Comment: `return this; //for chaining` is rubbish inside the event handler and can be omitted.

Comment: @Bergi - oh no, chaining is important, one should always return this and not that.

Comment: The question itself is worded wrong. Please change it.

Comment: Here's a protip, if you don't want to round the numbers remove the entire code, as that's all it does, round the number to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Change a little your code.
Remove the `.toFixed(2)` and add a regular expression to keep only the 2 digits after the punkt.

```
/(\d+\.\d{2})/i
```

`\d+` this gets the first digits before punkt,
`\.` this is the punkt,
`\d{2}` this only takes 2 digits
and by using the `()` we can get the code on the second index of the array so we get the item `[1]`. We apply the regular expression with the `.match` method.
[More about regular expression here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

So here is the code:

```
$( function() {
    $('.two-digits').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().indexOf('.')!=-1){         
            if($(this).val().split(".")[1].length > 2){
                if( isNaN( parseFloat(this.value.match(/(\d+\.\d{2})/i)[1])) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value.match(/(\d+\.\d{2})/i)[1]);
            }  
         }            
         return this;
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/A24YA/1/

Comment: It would be very helpful for others if you explained why you suggest this solution (and what it does exactly).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
Math.floor(this.value * 100) / 100
```